# Python - Check if word matches list of words with IF statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to check with an IF if a particular string matches a few words at the same time. Put in code, it would be like this:

```
if shippingDest == "Spain":
    shippingRegion = "Spain"
if shippingDest == "Portugal":
    shippingRegion = "Portugal"
if shippingDest == ["France", "Germany", "Luxembourg", "Belgium", "United Kingdom"]:
    shippingRegion = "Euro1"
if shippingDest == ["Albania", "Andorra", "Austria", "Belarus", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Bulgaria", "Croatia", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Estonia", "Faroe Islands", "Finland", "Georgia", "Gibraltar", "Greece", "Hongary", "Iceland", "Ireland", "Italy", "Latvia", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macedonia", "Malta", "Moldova", "Monaco", "Montenegro", "Netherlands", "Norway", "Poland", "Romania", "Russia", "San Marino", "Serbia", "Slovenia", "Svalbard and Jan Mayen", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Ukraine", "Vatican City State"]:
    shippingRegion = "Euro2"
else:
    shippingRegion = "World"
```

When checking this with, for example, Germany as the country, shippingRegion would be Euro1. However, it takes it as World.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to see if a word matches any of a set of words with an IF?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [the `in` operator](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#in):

```
if shippingDest == "Spain":
    shippingRegion = "Spain"
elif shippingDest == "Portugal":
    shippingRegion = "Portugal"
elif shippingDest in ["France", "Germany", "Luxembourg", "Belgium", "United Kingdom"]:
    shippingRegion = "Euro1"
elif shippingDest in ["Albania", "Andorra", "Austria", "Belarus", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Bulgaria", "Croatia", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Estonia", "Faroe Islands", "Finland", "Georgia", "Gibraltar", "Greece", "Hongary", "Iceland", "Ireland", "Italy", "Latvia", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macedonia", "Malta", "Moldova", "Monaco", "Montenegro", "Netherlands", "Norway", "Poland", "Romania", "Russia", "San Marino", "Serbia", "Slovenia", "Svalbard and Jan Mayen", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Ukraine", "Vatican City State"]:
    shippingRegion = "Euro2"
else:
    shippingRegion = "World"
```

When applied to a list, `in` operator checks for whether or not a value is contained in the list.

It might be better to use [a set](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#set) instead, as your values are not ordered. The set syntax is as follows:

```
{'something', 'something else', 'another thing', '...'}
```

It's similar to a list, except this data structure is not ordered. Like a list, you can also use `in` to check if a particular value is contained within a set.

Note: it seems you want `elif`, not `if` - using `if` makes any country that isn't in the `Euro2` zone become the `World` region instead, including Spain and Portugal.

Answer (score 4):

Replace `==` with `in`:

```
if shippingDest in ["France", "Germany", "Luxembourg", "Belgium", "United Kingdom"]:
```

Your code would also be more efficient if you replaced the `if` statements after the first with `elif`s, meaning `else if`.

Also, you could shorten it like this:

```
if shippingDest in ("France", "Germany", "Luxembourg", "Belgium", "United Kingdom"):
    shippingRegion = "Euro1"
elif shippingDest in ("Albania", "Andorra", "Austria", "Belarus", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Bulgaria", "Croatia", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Estonia", "Faroe Islands", "Finland", "Georgia", "Gibraltar", "Greece", "Hongary", "Iceland", "Ireland", "Italy", "Latvia", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macedonia", "Malta", "Moldova", "Monaco", "Montenegro", "Netherlands", "Norway", "Poland", "Romania", "Russia", "San Marino", "Serbia", "Slovenia", "Svalbard and Jan Mayen", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Ukraine", "Vatican City State"):
    shippingRegion = "Euro2"
elif shippingDest in ("Portugal", "Spain"):
    shippingRegion = shippingDest:
else:
    shippingRegion = "World"
```

I have also turned your lists into tuples (replaced `[]` with `()`) because you don't need to change them later, so making them immutable means less memory is used.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use elif's and `in` to check for membership instead of `==`

```
if shippingDest == "Spain":
    shippingRegion = "Spain"
elif shippingDest == "Portugal":
    shippingRegion = "Portugal"
elif shippingDest in ["France", "Germany", "Luxembourg", "Belgium", "United Kingdom"]:
    shippingRegion = "Euro1"
elif shippingDest in ["Albania", "Andorra", "Austria", "Belarus", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Bulgaria", "Croatia", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Estonia", "Faroe Islands", "Finland", "Georgia", "Gibraltar", "Greece", "Hongary", "Iceland", "Ireland", "Italy", "Latvia", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macedonia", "Malta", "Moldova", "Monaco", "Montenegro", "Netherlands", "Norway", "Poland", "Romania", "Russia", "San Marino", "Serbia", "Slovenia", "Svalbard and Jan Mayen", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Ukraine", "Vatican City State"]:
    shippingRegion = "Euro2"
else:
    shippingRegion = "World"
```

What's happening is that shippingDest is being set correctly, then failing the last if, so the else clause is executed, resulting in `World`.

It'd make more sense, and be more maintainable if you had a lookup table, using a `dict`:

```
shipping_destinations = {
    'Portugal': 'Portugal',
    'France': 'Euro1',
    'Monaco': 'Euro2',
    'spain': 'Spain'
}
```

Then, once those were listed out, you could do:

```
ship_to = shipping_destinations.get(country_name, 'World')
```

To retrieve the destination or default it to world. This saves if statements and if you had a spreadsheet of zones, would be easy to populate from that...

Comment: If only I could rep and vote more than 1 answer! Thanks, this provides a different and more efficient way to do it, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 2):

```
if shippingDest == ["France", "Germany", "Luxembourg", "Belgium", "United Kingdom"]:
    shippingRegion = "Euro1"
```

This does not see if `shippingDest` is one of those strings, **instead** it checks if `shippingDest` is **equal to that list**.

Instead, you could use:

```
if shippingDest in ["France", "Germany", "Luxembourg", "Belgium", "United Kingdom"]:
    shippingRegion = "Euro1"
```

Since the preceding conditionals evaluated to false, the `else` executed.  Additionally, for mutually exclusive conditions, you want to use `elif` instead of a series of `if` statements followed by one else.  In your code, that `else` only corresponds to the preceding `if`.

Comment: Thanks to all the quick answers. Truly impressed with the open source community and the help I'm getting. Cheers to all!

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the keyword `elif` - which is analogous to other languages `else if`.

Additionally, you want to test if the string ("Germany") is IN the list, use the `in` keyword instead of `==`.

Answer (score 2):

Try `in` :

```
if shippingDest in ["France", "Germany", "Luxembourg", "Belgium", "United Kingdom"]:
    shippingRegion = "Euro1"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use IN

```
if shippingDest in ["France", "Germany", "Luxembourg", "Belgium", "United Kingdom"]:
```